# Linking include directory of imported library

Tags: cmake

I have two standalone projects in the following directory structure.

```
├── main
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── main.cpp
└── mylib
    ├── bar.cpp
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── foo.cpp
    └── inc
        ├── bar.hpp
        └── foo.hpp
```

`main` is using the `mylib` library.

I create the library in `mylib/CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.3)
project(mylib)

# ...
 
add_library(mylib STATIC foo.cpp bar.cpp)

target_include_directories( mylib PRIVATE "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc" "$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}>")

install(TARGETS mylib
        EXPORT mylibtargets
        LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
        INCLUDES DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR})   

install(FILES "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc/foo.hpp" "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc/bar.hpp" DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR})

install(EXPORT mylibtargets DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake)
```

I include this library in `main/CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.3)
project(main)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

include("/abs_path/mylib/install/lib/cmake/mylibtargets.cmake")

add_executable(main main.cpp)

# not necessary:
#target_include_directories(main PRIVATE "../mylib/inc")

target_link_libraries(main mylib)
```

This code works perfectly fine, but I don't understand why I do not have to include the headers of  `mylib` to build `main` using `target_include_directories`. In  `mylib/CMakeLists.txt` I include the header directory PRIVATE. Thus, it shouldn't be visible to `main`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I suppose this is due to `INCLUDES DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}) `, but I am not fully sure...

Comment: Not sure, but since it makes little sense to specify an include directory for the installed version of the lib that is private, maybe this dir becomes public automatically. You could check the generated configuration script to check, which include dirs are added to the target maybe modifying `mylib/CMakeLists.txt` to see, if something changes...

Comment: If both projects in a single tree, there is no reason to install the lib before use in the `main` project (and do `include`)... You can use `add_subdirectory(mylib)` and build it as a part of the top-level project.

Answer (score 0):

I could figure out the answer on my own. TheList of public include directories for a library. The `INCLUDES DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR})` option adds the the include directory to the `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property of the target when exported by the install(EXPORT) command. This property contains a list of `public` include directories.

That means that the `PRIVATE` option in `target_include_directories` is ignored.